# Automaton without variables and guards for queueing system

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Disclaimer: Assignment question.

I am trying to solve the below question, the condition is not to use guards and variables. Is it at all possible to do this?

[image]

My approach was to have 4 separate automatons, 1 for each of the three servers and 1 for the entire system(with states for 0, 1 and 2 customers in the system). But its not working for all the conditions.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One deterministic automaton is enough to model this system.

Here are the list of states and their meanings. The alphabet is $$\{\text{a_customer_comes},\text{a_customer_leaves_server_1},\\ \text{a_customer_leaves_server_2},\text{a_customer_leaves_server_3}\}.$$ (We assume the input events happen one at a time. Otherwise, the problem might be too ill-defined enough to have a unique answer or too complex to be done as an exercise.)

$q_{0,0,0}$ : the initial state. No customer present.
$q_{1,0,0}$ : 1 customer at server 1 and 0 customer at server 2 and 0 customer at server 3.
$q_{0,1,0}$ : 0 customer at server 1 and 1 customer at server 2 and 0 customer at server 3.
$q_{0,0,1}$ : 0 customer at server 1 and 0 customer at server 2 and 1 customer at server 3.
$q_{1,1,0}$ : 1 customer at server 1 and 1 customer at server 2 and 0 customer at server 3.
$q_{1,0,1}$ : 1 customer at server 1 and 0 customer at server 2 and 1 customer at server 3.
$q_{0,1,1}$ : 0 customer at server 1 and 1 customer at server 2 and 1 customer at server 3.

I will let you figure out the transitions.